# Upload file using slackbot as Direct message

Tags: slack-api, slack

I am created slack bot, is there is any possible way send reply message as file? (I need to sent some file as reply message based on input). I tried using api file.upload it make the file as private not able access using url, but if i am upload to channel using sampe api, file is public, is there any way to send direct message as file by bot)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can share a file directly and privately with a user by sharing it in a direct message channel with the user.

Just put the `{user-id}` of the user you want to share the file with in the `channels` parameter of the [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) API method and you are all set.

Your slack app will need the `files:write:user` scope. This also works with bots.

Example for user with ID `U12345678`:

```
curl -F content="Hello" -F channels=U12345678 -F token=xoxp-your-token-here  https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```